# adding another row of items to UITabBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbar

I have a "more" item, which upon click should show an additional `UITabBar` row of `UITabBarItems` on top of the existing tab bar

Is it possible?

Comment: if you have more than 4 tabs, "More" option will come by default. this is what you want

Comment: I have more... When a user clicks more I want to "open" another tabbar above the current

Comment: oh. you are saying that if I have more than 4 it is handled automatically?

Comment: ya UITabbar will handle it

Comment: well, tried it - it has an ugly default screen with the rest of the items, and the ability to the user to organize the TabBar - that is not what I intended. Can I override this functionality?

Comment: Nop. You may want to use custom tabbar controller. Check [this](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/crtabbarcontroller--2)